# Negotiating a direct SSH connection between two hosts behind NATs, using a third host

Tags: networking, nat

Currently I'm using `ssh -R <stuff> B` from my desktop (call it `C`, which is in a NAT) so that I can SSH to it from my laptop (`A`), wherever I am. However, I'd like to remove the extra latency introduced by going `A->B->C`, by somehow negotiating a connection `A->C`.

There are several questions about how to establish a peer-to-peer connection between two hosts which are behind NATs. The answers generally suggest using [pwnat](http://samy.pl/pwnat/). It seems like the main function of pwnat is to get the client's IP to the server, but since I can just send that information to `C` via `B`, that's not needed here. Given that I can send whatever information I want between `A` and `C`, is there any way for me to set up a direct tunnel between them?

Comment: "It seems like the main function of `pwnat` is to get the client's IP to the server, but since I can just send that information to `C` via `B`, that's not needed here." – No, the main function is to establish and keep a tunnel. The feature of discovering the client's IP should not interfere with what you want to do. Only by reading the documentation you linked to, I learned the same author has created a tool without the feature:`chownat`. I guess any of these tools may work well in your case. Have you tried to use one or the other?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes I tried pwnat, but it didn't work. My understanding is that it relies on NAT behavior which is no longer standard. I'll take a look at chownat though.

Comment: Actually nevermind, it looks like chownat was the predecessor to pwnat, so I think neither of those tools will work. I was hoping the existence of another band of communication would allow the two machines which are NAT-ed to communicate whatever information is necessary to establish a tunnel.

Comment: As you wrote, it depends on what NAT is available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation . See the different types and the NAT traversal paragraph. CG-NAT is about the same as symmetric NAT: the case where not much can be done if both sides are like this.